# Why is this failing to correctly post a file from a folder in Python3 with the requests library?

Tags: python-3.x, file, flask, post, request

So the error occurrs on 475 which is identified in the line in the code below...For the life of my I open the file correctly and appear to put in in the correct dictionary to send through the post..just not sure why I'm seeing what I'm seeing in terms of error.

```
if test == '1':
        app.logger.info("Debug log level")
        directory = '/opt/cmsapi/F5_INJEST'
        thefile = random.choice(os.listdir(directory))
        try:
            file = {'fieldname',open(directory+'/'+thefile,'rb')} <<line 475..
        except Exception as e:
            app.logger.info("Exception")
        app.logger.info("File") 
        app.logger.info(file)
        try:
            requests.post("https://server/f5intake",files=file)
        except Exception as e:
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
            app.logger.info(fname)
            app.logger.info(exc_tb.tb_lineno)
            app.logger.info("test")
            app.logger.info(str(e))
            return '1'
```

Thee output to the custom log file...

```
INFO:flask.app:Start log level
 INFO:flask.app:1
 INFO:flask.app:Debug log level 
 INFO:flask.app:File
 INFO:flask.app:{'fieldname',<_io.BufferedReader name='/opt/cmsapi/F5_INJEST/bipsc3qa-Mon-Jun-12-0356.out.csv'>}
 INFO:flask.app:connect.py
 INFO:flask.app:475
 INFO:flask.app:test
 INFO:flask.app:too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: I believe it should be file = {'fieldname': open(directory+'/'+thefile,'rb')} (note the : instead of the ,)

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow Nailed it... too much coding... appreciated..